# Single parsley.js error message for multiple fields

Tags: parsley.js

I'm looking for a way to use a single parsley validation error message for a set of input fields. The primary example of this would be for an address input field, but I'm sure others can come up with similar examples where this might be useful.

```html
<div id="error-container"></div>
<input name='address1' data-parsley-maxlength="255" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
<input name='address2' data-parsley-maxlength="255" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
<input name='address3' data-parsley-maxlength="255" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
```

Using the above code right now would result in 3 different error messages, but I want to set up a scenario where only one message would be displayed if any of the inputs are invalid.

Thanks in advance

## Update

After a bit of JS console fun, I think I've found something that works. The idea below is to prevent any UI changes being done by parsley on the group, and to trigger a check on the whole group each time one of the elements are validated. This may not be the best way to do things, but it appears to be working with my single test-case. I'm thinking that this could be re-worked into a validator so that I can re-use it for other sets of inputs in the future.

```html
<div id="error-container"></div>
<input name='address1' data-parsley-ui-enabled='false' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-group='address-grp' data-parsley-maxlength="255" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
<input name='address2' data-parsley-ui-enabled='false' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-group='address-grp' data-parsley-maxlength="255" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
<input name='address3' data-parsley-ui-enabled='false' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-group='address-grp' data-parsley-maxlength="255" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
```

```js
var $addressFields = $("[data-parsley-group='address-grp']");
addressFields.each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).parsley().on('field:validated', function(parsleyField) {
    var fieldOptions = parsleyField.actualizeOptions().options;
    var classHandler = fieldOptions.classHandler(parsleyField);
    var container = $(fieldOptions.errorsContainer);
    classHandler.removeClass(fieldOptions.successClass);
    classHandler.removeClass(fieldOptions.errorClass);
    var valid = parsleyField.parent.isValid(fieldOptions.group);
    if(valid) {
      console.log("Valid");
      classHandler.addClass(fieldOptions.successClass);
      container.html("");
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid");
      classHandler.addClass(fieldOptions.errorClass);
      container.html("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this fairly cleverly with a bit of CSS if you add a particular class to your error container.

HTML:

```
<div id="error-container" class="parsely-single-error"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.parsely-single-error .filled ~ .filled {
    display: none;
}
```

---

### Explanation

The CSS reads, "hides any child elements of the error-container that have the class 'filled' and come after another element that has the class 'filled'".  This has the effect of hiding all but the first 'filled' error in the error container.

For reference, the parsely error container looks like this when filled:

```
<div class="parsely-single-error" id="error_container">
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-5">
        <div class="parsley-required">This value is required.</div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block" id="parsley-id-7"></span>
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-9">
        <div class="parsley-required">This value is required.</div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-11">
        <div class="parsley-required">This value is required.</div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block" id="parsley-id-13"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really quite clever. We obviously addressed this a year and a half ago, but I'll see if I can dig up how we solved it. I know it wasn't this, but I think it may have been something similar.

Thanks for reminding me that this was still open. I prefer to mark questions completed and I guess I forgot this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there a great way to do this.

You could try configuring it so that errors are put in the same container, and then use CSS to only show the `:first` of them?

Comment: That's probably a much simpler solution than what I was digging into. I'll give it a try shortly.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I think that might've worked except for another requirement that I hadn't even realized I needed to deal with. Right now, I need to mark the whole form-group (div containing the inputs) as success/error. If I only show the error for the first, then some of them show success, some show error.

Comment: can you show me the source code, i use this code nothing work

div.pin-number > ul.parsley-errors-list > li.parsley-required:not(:first-child)
{
    display: none;
}

Comment: This won't work.  Parsley puts a span in the error container for each field, and then fills those in if there are errors.